# Creating list with dates

Tags: python

I have created a function that extracts the "date" of each article that I have in a text file (4 or 5th row of each article). The challenge is now to create a text file with just the month and the year. Here is my function main:

```
def main():
    for i in range(len(sections)): 
        print(sections[i].split("\n")[4])       
        print(sections[i].split("\n")[5])
main()
```

Which gives me the following text:[image]

As it can be seen, the dates are not stored in every column. Moreover, the date format varies: those stored in row 4 of my original text appear with the date (first 6 of them), whereas those which were stored in column 5 appear without the date.

Ideally the text file would look like:

1. December 2005
2. December 2005
3. December 2005
4. December 2005
5. December 2005
6. November 2005
7. ....

   Thanks a lot!

Comment: remove image, put text.

Comment: And show us what is `sections` looks like?

Comment: split text with data (using space) and get first and third element - it should be always month and year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping as much as possible your code structure, this should be the solution you are looking for. It's meant to be easy to read and understand. However it is not the best solution, for that we need to know what selection looks like, or even better what your input file looks like.

```
def main():
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in range(len(sections)):
            date_row4 = sections[i].split("\n")[4].split(" ")
            date_row5 = sections[i].split("\n")[5].split(" ")

            print(date_row4)
            print(date_row5)

            month_row4 = date_row4[1]
            year_row4 = date_row4[3]

            month_row5 = date_row5[1]
            year_row5 = date_row5[3]

            if len(month_row4): # avoid to write empty lines in the output
                f.write("{} {}{}".format(month_row4,year_row4,'\n'))
            if len(month_row4):
                f.write("{} {}{}".format(month_row5,year_row5,'\n'))
main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks really good however is not filling the output text file with anything. I corrected the small mistake of double writing month_row4 and year_row4 and replace them with a 5. I will keep working on your answer, thanks!

Comment: Yes, the file.write() method was called wrongly, now it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to build regular expression  to extract the different parts out of the string, day, year, month. Then once you have the different components you can easily arrange them in the format you want and writing to a text file at that point is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be

```
def main():

    for s in sections:

        lines = s.split("\n")

        if lines[4]:
            parts = lines[4].split(' ')
            print(parts[0], parts[2]) 

        if lines[5]:
            parts = lines[5].split(' ')
            print(parts[0], parts[2])
```

**EDIT:** with numbers

```
def main():

    for number, s in enumerate(sections, 1):

        lines = s.split("\n")

        if lines[4]:
            parts = lines[4].split(' ')
            print(number, parts[0], parts[2]) 

        if lines[5]:
            parts = lines[5].split(' ')
            print(number, parts[0], parts[2])
```